# Al utilizar querySelector(), arroja que la variable es null

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy haciendo una calculadora. Ya hice todas las funcionalidades pero no puedo probarla porque hay un elemento que lo impide y es precisamente la pantalla donde se debería mostrar lo que el usuario pulsa, pero cuando en mi variable le aplico el `innerText` para que se refleje lo que el usuario pulsó, me arroja que la variable es `null`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es-ES">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Mi Primera App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
    <script src="codigo.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="contenedor">
        <section class="pantalla">
            0
        </section>

        <section class="botones-calc">
        <div class="botones-calcula-fila">
        </div>
        <div class="botones-calcula-fila">
        </div>
        <div class="botones-calcula-fila">
        </div>
        <div class="botones-calcula-fila">
        </div>
        <div class="botones-calcula-fila">
        </div>
           
        </section>
    </div>
</body>
```

El javascript es este:

```
let totalActualizado = 0;
let memoriaTemporal = "0";
let operadoresUsados;

const pantalla = document.querySelector(".pantalla");
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Agrega el error que te sale.

Comment: ¿Usas `defer` cuando cargas el script (archivo js)? Primero tiene que cargar el HTML, después el JS.

Comment: Por favor, muestra tu código HTML al completo, o al menos la zona donde incluyes tu script `codigo.js` ya que probablemente cuando buscas por el elemento con `querySelector` este todavía no exista en el documento HTML como tal. Puedes probar a incluir el código al final del cuerpo de tu código HTML o esperar por el evento `DOMContentLoaded`.

Comment: Agrega `defer` al `<script>` , así: `<script src=“codigo.js” defer>`

Comment: Gracias por su ayuda! colocando el defer pude solucionar y ya corre perfecto, supongo que el script se estaba cargando antes de que los elementos existieran.

Comment: Los `<script>` procura siempre ponerlos arriba del cierre de la etiqueta `</body>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solución:

Agregar `defer` al `<script>` porque el archivo JavaScript estaba cargando antes del HTML.

Resultado final:

```
<script src=“codigo.js” defer>
```

Más información y ejemplos:
[HTML  defer Attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_defer.asp)

Comment: Otra opción es poner los scripts al final del HTML.